# Python - How to remove similar elements from a list?

Tags: python, list, element

For example I have a list:

```
L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 10, 1, 3]
```

And I want to remove all 1's from the list, so that I would get:

```
L = [2, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3]
```

I tried iterating over the list and then deleting the element if it equals the element I want to delete (1 in this case), but turns out you can't iterate and delete stuff from a list at the same time since it messes up the counting. The best thing I've come up with is just construct a new list L2 that doesn't contain any of the 1's and then put that into L, but is there a solution that only involves mutating L?

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but is there a solution that only involves mutating L?

You can rather iterate over a copy of your List - `L[:]`, and remove element from `L`. That won't mess up counting.

If you really don't want to create a new list, you would have to iterate in reverse using `range(len(L) - 1, -1, -1)`, but that won't be 'Pythonic' anymore.

```
>>> for x in L[:]:  
...     if x == 1:
...         L.remove(x)
... 
>>> L
[2, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3]
```

---

However, you can also use *List Comprehension*:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 10, 1, 3]
>>> L[:] = [x for x in L if x != 1]
>>> L
[2, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3]
```

Comment: What is the meaning of using `L[::-1]` not `L[:]`? It's a new copy of `L`, reverse or not reverse do not matter.

Comment: @zhangyangyu. Yeah there is no difference. Anyways, I already updated the answer with more sensible text. ;)

Comment: Note that your first method is `O(N^2)`, while the second one is better as it is `O(N)` and it can also be used to mutate `L` if you use: `L[:] = [x for x in L if x != 1]`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Umm. It's same as `L = [x for x in L if x != 1]` right? Both are changing `L` only.

Comment: @RohitJain No, there's a difference. If you had something like `A = L = [1,1,2,3,4]` then using `L[:] = [x for ...]` will affect both `A` and `L`,i.e `L`'s `id()` remains same. But `L = [x for ...]` will only modify `L`.

Comment: Or to make it more tangible: The noticeable difference is what happens to L1 in the following: `L1 = L; /* change L in one of the two ways */`.  `L[:]` will also cause L1 to have the new contents, at the cost of O(N) vs. O(1) obviously.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer!

One thing that concerns me, is that aren't you creating another list when you use a comprehension? I mean, a comprehension is like a function that returns a list right? So you create a new list based on the conditions in the comprehension, and then stick that into L, but you are still creating a new list. I'm new to Python, so I'm not sure if I am right, but it seems logical

Comment: @NorsulRonsul. Yeah that is creating a new list. But that shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @NorsulRonsul. As I said, if you really don't want to create a new list, use `range()` to iterate in reverse. But, again you should use the way which is more readable, and suitable for you. Using `range()` to iterate a list is certainly not Pythonic.

Comment: I understand that writing readable code should usually be the goal, but in this case conserving memory was important. I don't know much about memory handling yet, but to my knowledge creating a new array will take up additional memory before it replaces the old one. That's why I didn't want to create a new list.

Answer (score 2):

Using the filter built-in:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 10, 1, 3]
>>> filter(lambda x: x is not 1, L)
[2, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3]
```

Or you can assign it back to `L`:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 10, 1, 3]
>>> L = filter(lambda x: x is not 1, L)
>>> L
[2, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3]
```

---

You can also wrap this concept into methods, to be able to specify a list of items to include/exclude:

```
def exclude(collection, exclude_list):
    return filter(lambda x: x not in exclude_list, collection)

def include(collection, include_list):
    return filter(lambda x: x in include_list, collection)
```

---

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 10, 1, 3]
>>> L = exclude(L, [1])
>>> L
[2, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3]
```

Comment: Using filter in this day and age is not really pythonic *and* doesn't solve the "problem" of it creating a new list instead of mutating the existing one.

Comment: There is no real difference between mutating a list from A to B, or creating B and assigning it to A. If done properly.

Comment: I invite you to create a really large list and look at your memory consumption when trying both different approaches. The inherent problem of it taking up to twice the memory is impossible to avoid even if "done properly" (whatever that means) [in python at least, extremely clever compilers could maybe do some tricks, but I doubt any language/compiler combination could do something like this atm).

Comment: The difference becomes memory consumption versus processing power.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mutate the list or generate any new copy of it. You can loop from end to begin and use index:

```
>>> for i in range(len(L)-1, -1, -1):
...     if L[i] == 1:
...         del L[i]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am confused with output of `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

This is awkward to do in python without making a copy of the list...

This will do it without making a copy.

```
a = range(6)  # Some array [0,1,2,3,4,5]
i=0
while i < len(a):
  if a[i] == 4:
    del a[i]
  else:
    i += 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```